# Excel VBA - Using nest if's and vlookups referencing 2 combobox values

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, match, vlookup

I've been tasked with trying to make an Excel workbook that's got a level of complexity which is frankly way way outside my usual wheelhouse. I've managed to get some of small pieces working but I'm struggling to make headway on bringing it together.

The end-goal is to make a kind of audit/tracker spreadsheet. Order of business:

**1:** User selects data from 3 combo boxes (these have some dependencies involving named ranges from another sheet in the book)

**2:** User types in the new data to be set

**3:** User confirms action, old data is copied to a third sheet for historical/tracking, and new data is entered in its place on the second sheet.

**4:** Document is saved post edit.

Now I've got most of step 1 working, the first two combobox populate with the relevant data (the second box has a dependency on the first) the third combobox is manually populated on document open.

I've got code for steps 3 and 4 from other work I've done in the past (plagiarism is an accepted truth right?)

It's step 2 that I'm appealing for help with.

Casting my mind back to mid 90's university I've sketched out some pseudo-code to give me some direction, but I'm really struggling to work out how to achieve it.

```
When user clicks on combobox_product:

check value of combobox_status

check value of combobox_tenant

check value of combobox_product

lookup client on sheet matching value of status
fill cells D12, E12, G12 & I12 based on vlookup of client where product equals pertinent table
```

Then when the user has filled in row 14 with the new data, they can hit a submit button which kicks off the copy work and saves the document.

To assist, here's some visuals:
[image: Form Page]

[image: Example data page]

As it stands, I think I need to do this with a complex IF within a more basic IF, with the complex IF having a combination of VLookup's and Match maybe? With probably a FOR to fill the rows out?

Comment: Your questions mixes different terms to the point where it's harder to follow than it needs to be.  eg tenant/client product/software it's not clear if these are the same or what?

Comment: Hi Tim - this would be a reflection of trying to write something coherent after being awake for far too long.

Tenant/Client - Same thing.
Product/Software - Same thing.

So in essence, the user selects if it's Live or Test, selects the Client/Tenant, Selects the Product. Row 12 then populates with the relevant data from the second image. They enter their new data in the Row 14, then hits a submit button (not visible on image 1) the old data gets copied out to a third sheet used as a change tracker, and the new data gets pasted in.

Comment: You can use Match() on client to find the correct row, then Match() again on product to locate the correct column (a bit complicated by those merged cells).  Once you have row and column you can copy the data you want for editing.